# New Date.getDate() not working while adding days in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to add a certain number of days to `currentDate`. 
But the date returned is something weird. The same date if I am trying to subtract with number of days it works fine. Also if I am hardcoding the value instead of taking it from `document.getElementById` it works fine.
P.S : `document.getElementById` is returning proper value.

```
var someDateForFuture = new Date();
var numberOfDaysToCalculateForFuture = document.getElementById('futureDateCal').value;
someDateForFuture.setDate(someDateForFuture.getDate() + numberOfDaysToCalculateForFuture); 
alert(someDateForFuture);
```

Now if I have added 3 to number of days of current date, the alert displays

> Sat Apr 01 2017 11:23:57 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Please guide.

Comment: How can this be duplicate. I am not asking how to add number of days. I have issue while adding number of days

Comment: its working in my case

Comment: https://jsbin.com/zasolefumi/edit?html,output

Comment: parseInt() the value you are getting from html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this logic should work in this case.

```
var someDateForFuture= new Date(someDateForFuture.setTime( someDateForFuture.getTime() + numberOfDaysToCalculateForFuture* 86400000 ));
```

Answer (score 2):

`value` is returning a string. First make it into a number, and then add the values:

```
var future = new Date();
var days = +(document.getElementById('futureDateCal').value);

if (!isNaN(days)) {
    future.setDate(future.getDate() + days); 
}
else {
    alert("Non-numeric input");
}

alert(future);
```

Answer (score 1):

parseInt() the value you are getting from html

```
var someDateForFuture = new Date();
var numberOfDaysToCalculateForFuture = parseInt(document.getElementById('futureDateCal').value);
someDateForFuture.setDate(someDateForFuture.getDate() +numberOfDaysToCalculateForFuture); 
 alert(someDateForFuture);
```